# trying to use another properties key value in another properties key by using a subclass of Properties to override getProperty() method

Tags: java, properties, subclass

im trying to use another properties key value in another properties key by using a subclass of Properties class to ovveride getProperty() method but im not able to get the expected key value i wanted from the properties file. this is where i got the sub class code https://coderanch.com/t/469713/java/reference-defined-property-key-properties

sub class

```
import java.util.Properties;


/**
*
* A subclass of Properties that allows recursive
* references for property values. For example,
*
* <pre><code>
* A=12345678
* B={A}90
* C={B} plus more
* </code></pre>
*
* will result in <code>getProperty("C")</code>
* returning the value "1234567890 plus more".
*
* @author: Chris Mair
*
* Copied from: http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/Java/archives/0612/mair/index.html

*/


//@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class XProperties extends Properties {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     
      private static final String START_DELIMITER = "${";
      private static final String END_DELIMITER = "}";
       
      @Override
      public String getProperty(String key) {
        String value = super.getProperty(key);
         
        if (value != null) {
          int startIndex = 0;
          int endIndex = 0;
          while ( (startIndex = value.indexOf(START_DELIMITER, endIndex)) >= 0
              && (endIndex = value.indexOf(END_DELIMITER, startIndex) ) >= 0) {
     
            String variableName = value.substring(startIndex + START_DELIMITER.length(), endIndex);
            // now call getProperty recursively to have this looked up
            String variableValue = null;
             
            if (!variableName.equals(key)) {
              // only recurse if the variable does not equal our own original  key
              variableValue = this.getProperty(variableName);
            }
             
            if (variableValue == null) {
              // when unable to find the variable value, just return it as the variable name
              variableValue = START_DELIMITER + variableName + END_DELIMITER;
            }
            value = value.replace(START_DELIMITER + variableName + END_DELIMITER, variableValue);
          } // while matches.
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Properties file

```
ROOTDIR=C:/test_PROJECT
LOCALDIRWEB=${ROOTDIR}/cfo_web
LOCALDIRSERVER=${ROOTDIR}/cfo_server
```

implemetation of the above class

```
import java.util.Properties;
public class GitClone {
static XProperties a = new XProperties();
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
        a.load(GitClone.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         File cfoWebDir = new File (a.getProperty("LOCALDIRWEB"));
         System.out.println(cfoWebDir);
```

Output when printed out

```
NOTHING PRINTED OUT
```

Expected output

```
C:\test_PROJECT\cfo_web
```

Any help with this? Im i doing the implementation wrong?

Comment: In the `GitClone` class, you load the `prop` instance, and then read the `a` instance (which is empty). You should do `a.load(...)`, and remove `prop`.

Comment: @Tiggerpls upvote my question as i have modified it with solution

Comment: Sorry I have to ask first, but does it work now ?

Comment: @Tigger yes it works fine now once changed to a.load

Comment: So now, it's not a question anymore. I think it was just a little mistake, so it will never be helpful to anyone else. If you agree with that, maybe you could simply delete the post ? And if you don't want to, you could get back to the previous version of the question, and post your own answer, I don't mind.